# C++ - Stack with Linked List - Bad Memory Error?

Tags: c++, stack, linked-list

I am currently writing stack that is being implemented with a linked list. I am get this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x75249617 in STACK_LinkedList.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x002ee8f8.
```

I believe it is possibly coming from either my `push()` or `pop()` functions. I can't find my error. I am fairly new to linked lists, so I have a little bit of a tough time finding errors.

Here is my `push()` function:

```
// Adds an item to the top of the stack
template <class S>
void Stack<S>::push(const S & e)
{
    NodePointer temp = new Node(e);

    if ( isEmpty() )
    {
        theTop = theFront = temp;
    }
    else
    {
            // Whatever is after top is stored in temp to keep track of it
        theTop->next = temp;

            // TheTop is stored in temp
        theTop = temp;  
        delete temp; 
    }
}
```

Here is my `pop()` function:

```
//Takes the item off the top of the stack
template <class S>
void Stack<S>::pop()
{
    if ( !isEmpty() )
    {        
                //temp node is set equal to the front
        NodePointer temp = theFront;

                //Holds the second to last node in the linked list
        NodePointer pred;

                //loops through until the node after temp is 0
        while (temp->next != 0)
        {
                        //sets the second to last as temp
            pred = temp ;

                        //basically "increments" temp to the next node
            temp = temp->next ;
        }

                //sets temp equal to the top
        temp = theTop;

                //the top is then set to its predecessor
        theTop = pred;

                //deletes what was known as the top
        delete temp;
    }

    else
        cout << "STACK IS EMPTY" << endl;

}
```

Thanks alot! I believe most of my logic is correct. I just am missing something small. If it's something else please tell me and i'll post that code.

Comment: Is this homework? If it is, tag it as homework; if not, just use the STL :)

Comment: What is the value of theTop after you pop an element from a stack with only one element?  Hint: not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not delete your `temp` in `push`! It's a part of the list. So when you access this data later, you get surely an exception.

Second, you have to initialize your `pred` with `NULL` in `pop()`, otherwise you'll get an undefined value assigned to `theTop` if the stack contains only 1 item.

Third, you should delete in `pop()` the Node which you allocated in `push()`.

In general, your approach seems to be not very efficient. You should better store the pointers other way round: from stack top to the bottom items. That way you won't need to traverse the whole stack on each `pop()`. Your code will be something like that:

```
void push(data)
{
    allocate new top
    new top's next is the old top
    store new top in the class
}

void pop()
{
    if empty, ERROR;
    new top = old top's next
    deallocate old top
}
```

Note that you don't need `theFront` at all.

Comment: You are awesome my friend...

I realized i did this the wrong way earlier, but I had already done it the inefficient way. When I went to fix it, along with your advice it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Your push function is deleting "temp".  However, temp points to the data you just added to your list.  If call delete on a pointer, you are not throwing away the pointer, but rather deleting the memory it points to!  Get rid of your delete statement in push and test that first (without pop).  I haven't looked over your pop function, but I will leave that as an exercise for you to check for errors after you test pop().

-Dan8080